# Mocking controller UrlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mocking, routes

I'm having problems retrieving the route url from controller.RouteUrl(routeName) method.
Here is my code for mocking the urls in my test method:

```
//Arrange
...
//Mock routes
var routes = RouteTable.Routes;

routes.Clear();
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminPaymentResult",      // Route name
    "Payment/Result");         // URL with parameters

routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminPaymentCancel",      // Route name
    "Payment/Cancel");         // URL with parameters

_controller.SetFakeUrlHelper(routes);
...
```

where the method SetFakeUrlHelper is defined as:

```
public static void SetFakeUrlHelper(this Controller controller, RouteCollection routes)
{
    var fakeHttpContext = FakeHttpContext();
    var requestContext = new RequestContext(fakeHttpContext, new RouteData());
    controller.Url = new UrlHelper(requestContext, routes);
}
```

and the method FakeHttpContext is defined as:

```
public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
{
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);

    return context.Object;
}
```

The problem is that when in my controller action I call

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    ...
    var callBackUrl = Url.RouteUrl("AdminPaymentResult");
    ...
}
```

I get an empty string instead of "Payment/Result" as expected...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should mock the [`ApplyAppPathModifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponsebase.applyapppathmodifier.aspx) method on the `response` which is internally used by the `UrlHelper`. So just add the following line inside your `FakeHttpContext` method and you will be good to go:

```
response
    .Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns<string>(x => x);
```